# How to get around Facebook's buggy timeline/feed/wall og:video embeds?

Tags: video, embed, facebook-opengraph, facebook-wall, facebook-timeline

Ever since the release of Timeline, getting videos to embed on Facebook has been very buggy. We have the following problems:

1. Facebook intermittently fails to grab the open-graph data for a URL. I tried the Linter also and it intermittently fails. We use Cloudflare for DNS and they said this is an open issue on Facebook's side. This has been a problem for us for over a month.
2. Facebook handles `text/html` type video embeds differently depending on whether the user had a Wall or Timeline. On the Wall it would show the correct URL from open-graph, but on Timeline it would show a different URL.
3. To get around the second bug, we abandoned our HTML5 embed and switched to SWF video embeds, which initially appear to work fairly consistently on Wall, Feed, and Timeline views (although at different width/height combinations). However, users reported only seeing a grey box when expanding the embed. I can repeat this by viewing the same post in my Feed or on my Timeline, but in the Feed it would correctly display the embed and on the Timeline it would just show a grey box.

Is there a way to improve Facebook's ability to scrape our URLs and is there a way to ensure our embeds display all the time? These bugs are all intermittent and inconsistent so it's hard to see if we are doing something wrong...

I should add we are specifying both `og:video` and `og:video:secure_url` embeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have actually pushed a fix for this issue (we worked with Facebook to get it resolved). The intermittent 503 errors are no longer appearing in our tests, so [please contact us](http://support.cloudflare.com/) if you see any other issues.